# Question on definition of $f^{-1}(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Assume $A$ and $X$ are arbitrary sets such that $X$ is not the empty set. let $f$ be a function from $X$ into $A$. I already know that $f^{-1}(B)$ is defined for every subset $B$ of $A$, but is it also defined for any set $C$, where $C$ might not even be related to $A$ in any kind of way? By not related here I mean that $A \cap C = \emptyset$ and that $C$ is not the empty set or that it contains $A$.

Edit: I asked this question because of the problem that I am currently facing due to this definition in Rudin rca:
Definition 3.7: Suppose $g$ is a measurable function from $X$ into $[0, \infty]$. Let $S$ be the set of all real $\alpha$ such that $$\mu(g^{-1}((\alpha, \infty])) = 0.$$ Now if $S = \emptyset$ then let $b = \infty$, but if $S$ is not empty then let $b$ = inf$S$.And then he mentions after this definition that if $S$ is not empty then $b$ is in $S$. However the problem lies here that if the measure of the $g^{-1}([0,\infty])$ is $0$ and we accept to assume $g^{-1}((\alpha, \infty])$ is defined for every real $\alpha$ then $b = -\infty$ and so Rudin's argument regarding $b \in S$ fails since $S$ is defined to be the set of reals.

Comment: No, you can only take the inverse image (precisely in subsets of $A$)

Answer (score 0):

If you treat $f$ as a function from $X$ into $A$ then $f^{-1}(B)$ is defined only for subsets $B$ of $A$. However if $Y$ is any set which contains $A$ then we can also regard $f$ as a function from $X$ into $Y$. In this case we can define $f^{-1}(B)$ for any subset $B$ of $Y$ including sets contained in $Y\setminus A$.

Comment: Is what you are saying about extending the definition for the inverse of f widely accepted?

Comment: Clearly, this makes $f^{1-}(B)=f^{-1}(B\cap A)$ for arbitrary $B$.

Comment: Usually,when you talk about a function you have a particular $X$ and $A$ in mind. In this case we can only define $f^{-1}(B)$ for subsets of $B$. What I am saying is if you come across the notation $f^{-1}(B)$  for some $B$ not contained in $A$ you can interpret it by enlarging $A$. As pointed out in above comment you can also write $f^{-1}(B)$ as $f^{-1}(B\cap A)$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen but you are assuming here that $f^{-1}(B)$ is defined for any arbitrary $B$, in that case it is true.